# Plotting security vs time traded with Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with many columns representing securities, and the index having the time of the day from 00:00 to 23:55 (each row is a 5 minute interval), and each cell has either a 1 or a 0. I'd like to plot some form of boxplot which can visualize the data similar to something like I have drawn here:

[image: Sketch of desired plot]
But I am getting confused since all I have are binary values and cannot use them when plotting against the time. I am restricted to using pandas and matplotlib.

Comment: Can you post a small example of how the dataframe looks? I think i got what your saying but just to be sure.

Comment: Here is an image to an example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RoYkI5yaxbLU5XdzNwaXBCTWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @dgouder. I believe that your question is quite similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880103/creating-horizontal-bar-plot-with-time-series-data-in-python/36992409#36992409 . Please, can you provide an example dataset?

Comment: It looks similar but the shape of the data and the approach look very different from what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be using the link that i commented above, although your initial dataset is different. The procedure consist in assign numerical values to each column and change the zeroes by NaN, as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("testdata.txt",parse_dates=0,index_col=0)
df = df.applymap(lambda x:x if x else pd.np.nan)
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns): df[col] = df[col]*n
df.plot(lw=10,legend=False)
plt.yticks(pd.np.arange(len(df.columns)), df.columns)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

the result dataframe is:

```
                     A   B   C    D  E
time                                  
2016-05-05 00:00:00  0 NaN NaN  NaN  4
2016-05-05 00:05:00  0 NaN NaN  3.0  4
2016-05-05 00:10:00  0 NaN NaN  3.0  4
2016-05-05 00:15:00  0 NaN NaN  3.0  4
```

and the plot:

[image]

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could use is the broken bar chart in matplotlib. The documentation is [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.broken_barh).

Here is a simple version i tested:
Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a way to vectorize the operations by equity.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['qqq'] = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
df['dia'] = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

ones = []
for col in df.columns:
    one = df[df[col].diff() != 0][:][col]
    one = one[one == 1]
    ones.append(one)

hranges = []
for col in df.columns:
    diff = df[df[col].diff() != 0]
    spread = pd.DataFrame(diff[col].index, columns=[col])
    spread = spread.set_value(len(spread), col, len(df[col].index))
    spread = spread.diff(periods=-1).fillna(spread[pd.isnull(spread.diff()) == True])*-1
    spread = spread.drop(spread.index[-1])
    re_index = pd.DataFrame(df[df[col].diff() != 0][:][col].tolist())
    re_index = re_index[re_index[0] == 0]
    hranges.append(spread.drop(re_index[re_index[0] == 0].index))
    hranges[j].columns = ['width']
    hranges[j]['hval'] = ones[j].index.tolist()
    cols = hranges[j].columns
    cols = cols[-1:] | cols [:-1]
    hranges[j] = hranges[j][cols]
    j += 1

vals = []
for j in range(len(hranges)):    
    val = [(hranges[j].hval[i], hranges[j].width[i]) for i in hranges[j].index]
    vals.append(val)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
j = 0
for col in df.columns:
    ax.broken_barh(vals[j], ((j+1)*10,10))
    j += 1
ax.set_yticks([((k+1) * 10) + 5 for k in range(j)])
ax.set_yticklabels(df.columns)    
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Obviously your example would have a time value for the x axis but I imagine you could figure that out.